# CGAffineTransformInvert does not reverse view transformation

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

I want to scale+translate a view and then animate this transformation back. But CGAffineTransformInvert returns a transformation that does something different (cannot understand the logic of it).

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TestView : UIView {
    UIView *view;
    CGAffineTransform transform;
}
@end


#import "TestView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@implementation TestView
- (void)testAnimation:(NSString*)animationID finished:(NSNumber*)finished context:(void*)context {
    CGAffineTransform transformInverted = CGAffineTransformInvert(transform);
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"test2" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    view.transform = transformInverted;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 150, 100, 100)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [self addSubview:view];

        CGAffineTransform transform1 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(view.transform, -150, -150); 
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform1, (float)1/2, (float)1/2); 

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"test1" context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(testAnimation:finished:context:) ];

        view.transform = transform;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Try replacing statement  

    view.transform = transformInverted;  

with  

    view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(view.transform, transformInverted);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CGAffineTransformInvert` inverts the transform matrix, and returns a matrix that when multiplied by the original results in the `CGAffineTransformIdentity`.

If you want to invert the translation/scale, you should track them yourself.

PS. Matrices are very complex, they don't store the translation/scale/rotation values, they are composed of several values that when multiplied by the coordinates give you the translated/scaled/rotated values, so you can't expect to invert the matrix and get a matrix with the translation, scale and rotations inverted.

You can read more about them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix).

EDIT TO ANSWER YOUR COMMENT:

When working with matrices, the order of operations matters a lot, if you rotate and then translate, the result will be different than if you translate and then rotate.

To reverse the operations applied to a matrix, you should apply the opposite operations in the reverse order, in this case, to reverse this:

```
CGAffineTransform transform1 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(view.transform, x1, x2);
CGAffineTransform transform2 = CGAffineTransformScale(transform1, r1, r2);
CGAffineTransform transform3 = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform2, a);
```

You'd need to do this:

```
CGAffineTransform reversed3 = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform3, -a);
CGAffineTransform reversed2 = CGAffineTransformScale(reversed3, 1/r1, 1/r2);
CGAffineTransform reversed1 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(reversed2, -x1, -x2);

[view setTransform:reversed1];
```

If you hadn't modified the view's transform before, you can just do:

```
[view setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
```

Which is zero rotation, zero translation, and a scale of 1.

Comment: Thank you. Now I see - I could not expect this. Actually I need to invert CGAffineTransform transform1 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(view.transform, x1, x2); 
CGAffineTransform transform2 = CGAffineTransformScale(transform1, r1, r2);
CGAffineTransform transform3 = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform2, a);
If it is easy for you can you tell me how?

Comment: I edited my answer to answer the question in your comment. Hope it helps

Comment: thanks a lot. The order of operations matters! Now it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but shouldn't you simply change the view's transform back to `CGAffineTransformIdentity` in the testAnimation method?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to *animate* it back, not just place at the original position. It turned out to be not easy when you combine two animations (e.g. scale+translate or rotate+translate) because scale/rotate somehow modifies traslate behavior. And I cannot understand how.

Comment: Did you try it with just a translation for example? Just curious if at least the basics works.

Comment: A transformation matrix is an end result. It encodes a set of changes, but not how you got there. If you do an animation in several steps, you will need to explicitly do those steps in reverse in order to run your animation backwards. Also, concatenating transformation matrixes is rather confusing. I always have to dig out a book on animation to figure out what order to apply transforms to get the desired effect. I'd suggest looking for a good book on 3D graphics. Most will cover the math behind concatenating transforms.

Answer (score 0):

Consider code below. 
Here we have transformTest, then we applying transform3 on top of it. Then we applying on top of result inverse of transform3. End result is pretty closer to transformTest (floating point precision less).

If you would do `view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(view.transform, transformInverted);` in your code it will work.

```
CGAffineTransform transformStart = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGAffineTransform transform1 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transformStart, 10, 23);
CGAffineTransform transform2 = CGAffineTransformScale(transform1, 2, 10);
CGAffineTransform transform3 = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform2, M_PI_4);

CGAffineTransform invertedTransform = CGAffineTransformInvert(transform3);


// here actual test
NSLog(@"--------------- here actual test ---------------");

CGAffineTransform transformTest = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(2, 15);
transformTest = CGAffineTransformRotate(transformTest, M_PI_2);
transformTest = CGAffineTransformScale(transformTest, 19, 0.4);
transformTest = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transformTest, -33, -19);
NSLog(@"transformTest %@", NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(transformTest));

CGAffineTransform transformTestMultiplied = CGAffineTransformConcat(transformTest, transform3);
NSLog(@"transformTestMultiplied %@", NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(transformTestMultiplied));

CGAffineTransform transformTestMultipliedByInverse = CGAffineTransformConcat(transformTestMultiplied, invertedTransform);
NSLog(@"transformTestMultipliedByInverse %@", NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(transformTestMultipliedByInverse));
```

Output of this one:

```
2016-07-19 13:49:22.034 testUIView[45050:69431115] --------------- here actual test ---------------
2016-07-19 13:49:22.034 testUIView[45050:69431115] transformTest [1.1634144591899855e-15, 19, -0.40000000000000002, 2.4492935982947065e-17, 9.5999999999999623, -612]
2016-07-19 13:49:22.034 testUIView[45050:69431115] transformTestMultiplied [-26.870057685088803, 134.35028842544403, -0.56568542494923812, -2.8284271247461898, 889.0751503711158, -4236.611249867763]
2016-07-19 13:49:22.034 testUIView[45050:69431115] transformTestMultipliedByInverse [0, 19, -0.40000000000000002, 0, 9.5999999999999162, -612]
```